# I want to display the list of forms submitted dynamically in angular ,by checking the checkbox date range

Tags: angular

I want to display the list of forms i have submitted by selecting the checkbox (which should carry the range of 1 -7,7-15,15-30 days ).

I am able to display the list of form names by selecting start and end date. But i want to add range to it.

```
</div>
<div class="col-lg-12" style="padding-top: 2;padding-left: 18">
    <label id="example-radio-group-label" style="padding-right: 8;font-weight: bold">Range Of Date
        :</label>
    <mat-radio-group aria-label="Select an option" 
    ** [(ngModel)]="selected">

        <mat-radio-button value="1" style="color: 
    #1B4F58;font-weight: bold" [checked]="false">Last 7 Days
        </mat-radio-button>
        <mat-radio-button value="2" style="color: 
        #1B4F58;font-weight: bold" [checked]="false">Last 15
        Days</mat-radio-button>
        <mat-radio-button value="3" style="color: 
        #1B4F58;font-weight: bold" [checked]="false">Last 30
        Days</mat-radio-button>
    </mat-radio-group>
</div>
```

After submitting button GetFormSubmissions this method is getting called and I am getting data.

I dont know how to bind the checkbox,and display list of forms in date range

Comment: are you using ReactiveForm or [(ngModel)]? What data you received?. In general, in Angular we has an input like `<input [(ngModel)]="variable">` or `<input formControl="myFormControl">` or, in a form `<input formControlName="nameControl">`, see https://angular.io/guide/forms-overview

Comment: Hi, could you please post a [mcve] of your code that exibits your issue?